# Run local 'Javascript Dependant' HTML file in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

When you open a local HTML file (that contains Javascript) using Internet Explorer a message appears saying

`Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls`

My Question: **Is there a way to ask IE or the user to allow local HTML files to run javascript?**

We are distributing a CD that displays our HTML based menu on AutoRun. The menu runs in the users browser and communicates infromation about whats on the CD (a Customisation Package so NOT an installer). Our menu relies heavily on JQuery so not being able to run Javascript is not good. We chose to make the menu in HTML, CSS, Javascript to achieve cross-platform compatibility.

**Is there a way to automatically run Javascript from a local HTML file in IE?**

Comment: can you append your post with information on which version of IE, and how you're causing IE to load your page? (not entirely sure what you mean with cross-platform compatibility when your CD apparently relies on a windows-only autorun...?)

Comment: You want to use a Mark of the Web.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for details, or just add:
`<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` below the doctype and above the opening HTML tag.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans AFAIK all versions of IE have this restriction so the version is irrelevant. The reason for using HTML, CSS, Javascript is because we can create a interactive menu quickly and easily as opposed to using Winforms, Win32, DirectX, etc.

Comment: You could possibly package your menu as a HTA (html application) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx although this would stop it being cross-platform

Comment: Just came back to recommend the HTA as another option.  One could include both HTML and HTA versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want The Mark of the Web:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx

There are three versions

- `<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->`
- `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`
- `<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->`

The formatting is very specific, down to placement and that a carriage return **and** linefeed must follow the closing `-->`.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Mark of the Web Example.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Hello, World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it really work? I just saw [this part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx#THE_LOCAL_MACHINE_ZONE_LOCKDOWN). "To mitigate this security risk, Internet Explorer **locks down** the Local Machine zone. When the user opens an HTML document, Internet Explorer **prohibits active content from running** and displays an Information bar. The user must then decide whether to permit the action that triggered the Information bar."

Comment: Does the caveat "as long as that security zone is more restrictive than the Local Machine zone" not apply?

Comment: @AlexW - I'm not near that machine right now to check settings, but it works in whatever setup I have.

Comment: This feature does not work in IE 11, unfrotunatelly.

Comment: In case it helps anyone... key point: must end with **carriage return and linefeed**. Unfortunately my NP++ settings were stripping away the CR leaving just the LF. Fortunately it is an easy fix in NP++ goto ```Edit > EOL Conversion > select Windows CR LF```

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer should ask if you want to allow it, typically by clicking that notification. There is also a setting to permanently allow it.