# Disable wpf webbrowser security warning

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` control in my app.It loads `.mht` files from apllicaions's current directory.However, i get a security warning saying : `To help protect your security,your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content`..I tried almost all the available solutions both on SO and msdn...I have tried this :

```
public void HideScriptErrors(WebBrowser wb, bool Hide)
{
     FieldInfo fiComWebBrowser = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
     if (fiComWebBrowser == null) return;
     object objComWebBrowser = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb);
     if (objComWebBrowser == null) return;
     objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objComWebBrowser, 
     new object[] { Hide });
}
```

And called it in `browser.Navigated` event but with no result...Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

That's because of system settings applicable to IE (and WebBrowser), one way to avoid it might be to host the mht file on the web.

EDIT:

We host our help in WebBrowser control, but to do it we distribute as HTML pages, and add this header to the top of every file

```
 <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

It's called the 'mark of the web', see [Will The Mark of the Web always ensure IE runs local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005663/will-the-mark-of-the-web-always-ensure-ie-runs-local-html-file)  It prevents warnings, although it won't fix your issue with MHT, it's a suitable alternative.

Comment: Not without changing the user's settings. To do that, if it's even possible would require elevated privileges and I'm not sure it's even the right thing to do.

Comment: :( can't seem to figure this thing out

Comment: i cannot apply that either because a method is generating the .mht files automatically and i have no control over it :(